# Erro na solução de problema

Tags: javascript

> Leia 2 valores inteiros e armazene-os nas variáveis A e B. Efetue a
> soma de A e B atribuindo o seu resultado na variável X. Imprima X
> conforme exemplo apresentado abaixo. Não apresente mensagem alguma
> além daquilo que está sendo especificado e não esqueça de imprimir o
> fim de linha após o resultado, caso contrário, você receberá
> "Presentation Error".
>
> **Entrada**
>
> A entrada contém 2 valores inteiros.
>
> **Saída**
>
> Imprima a mensagem "X = " (letra X maiúscula) seguido pelo valor
> da variável X e pelo final de linha. Cuide para que tenha um espaço
> antes e depois do sinal de igualdade, conforme o exemplo abaixo.

Neste exercício coloquei assim:

```
var a = 10
var b = 9

var X = a + b

console.log('X = ', X)
```

E mesmo assim lá está dizendo que está errado a resolução deste exercício. Por quê?

Estou iniciando na programação.

Comment: Acredito que você consiga [edit] sua pergunta melhorando o título. Algo como "erro na solução" não diz muita coisa sobre o real problema e contexto da sua pergunta. Leia mais em [Como escolher um bom título?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4394/5878) Aproveite também para fazer o [tour] pelo site.

Comment: Ok. Ja vou alterar. Obrigado.

Comment: Qual site deste exercicio?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Diria que é o [URI 1003](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1003).

Comment: Quanto ao erro, provavelmente porque você não está lendo, efetivamente, os valores, mas sim definindo-os como constantes.

Comment: @LucasCardoso esse é o exercício do URI Online Judge mesmo ou pegou de outro site?

Comment: Qual o erro que dá ? Se é no URI, existem vários tipos de erros com as suas respetivas descrições. Se for um "Presentation Error" você saberá que está a produzir o resultado correto mas formatado de forma errada. Quanto a javascript no URI ele é utilizado com Node, logo o input vem por um arquivo e é todo lido como uma `string` através da função `readFileSync`. O código de template fornecido divide por linhas com `var lines = input.split('\n');`. Por isso o seu primeiro valor viria em `lines[0]` e o segundo em `lines[1]` lembrando que tem de converter para inteiro para fazer o que pretende.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se for o [**urionlinejudge**](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt) mesmo, talvez você tenha selecionado `C (gcc)` ao invés de JavaScript (ao até outra linguagem) no combobox, conforme imagem:

[image: c (gcc) urionlinejudge]

Provavelmente deveria ser:

[image: javascript urionlinejudge]

Então creio que o código deveria ser isso, porque eles **quem irão** passar os valores para A e B pelo `stdin`:

> Nota aparentemente os testes automatizados do urionlinejudge não aceitam index, como `lines[0]` e `lines[1]` para pegar as linhas, então usei `.shift`, que remove um item da variavel e copia para a variavel desejada, assim:

```
var input = require('fs').readFileSync('/dev/stdin', 'utf8');
var lines = input.split('\n');

var a = parseInt(lines.shift());
var b = parseInt(lines.shift());

var X = a + b;

console.log('X = ', X);
```

No caso se for o **urionlinejudge** em português parece que já pede variável **SOMA**:

> Leia dois valores inteiros, no caso para variáveis A e B. A seguir, calcule a soma entre elas e atribua à variável SOMA. A seguir escrever o valor desta variável.

Então altere para isto:

```
var input = require('fs').readFileSync('/dev/stdin', 'utf8');
var lines = input.split('\n');

var a = parseInt(lines.shift());
var b = parseInt(lines.shift());

var SOMA = a + b;

console.log('SOMA = ', SOMA);
```

Um detalhe muito importante, aparentemente você deve deixar uma quebra de linha no final do script, pois sem isto é o que causa o erro `"Presentation Error"` que você citou, conforme a mensagem:

> don't forget to print the end of line, otherwise you will receive "Presentation Error"

Então ao invés disto:

> [image: sem quebra de linha no final do script]

Adicione a nova linha vazia (quebra de linha), assim:

> [image: com quebra de linha no final do script]

---

Depois de adicionar a quebra de linha no final agora apareceu corretamente:

[image: resposta correta no urionlinejudge]

Comment: "Nota aparentemente os testes automatizados do urionlinejudge não aceitam index, como lines[0] e lines[1]" - Mas aceitam. Já fiz vários dessa forma, agora há casos particulares em que dá erro. Mas suspeito que tenha a ver com a forma como o arquivo de entrada esteja codificado, ou outro pormenor qualquer que não contemplei.

Comment: `console.log` quebra sempre no fim. Nesses casos o erro que dá é mesmo `Wrong answer 100%`, mas vale relembrar que eles tem lá JS como beta ainda, por isso não sei que implicações isso possa ter nos testes.

Comment: Já apanhei um ou outro assim. Agora não me lembro de cabeça quais, mas já tento achar e mandar.

Comment: @Isac fechou, vou ter que sair, mas prometo ver o mais breve possivel hoje

Answer (score 2):

Vou explicar.

Quando você quer juntar dois valores, você deve usar + dentro do console log entre os valores, e não outra virgula. A virgula passa outro parâmetro para a função, logo:

```
console.log('X = ', X); // output: X =  19 << note que tem dois espaços
console.log('X = ' + X); // output: X = 19 << correto.
```

Isso se dá por que ao invés de concatenar a variável com a string, você passou a variável como uma nova entrada pra função, e portanto, por default vai ser impresso com um espaço entre os outputs (ele considera o 'X = ' um output, e a variável X outro)
Se fosse feito dessa forma:

```
console.log('X =', X); //output: X = 19
```

funcionaria corretamente. Mas no caso, como tinha um espaço no final da string, ele se soma com o espaço entre o segundo output.

Comment: Verdade, tinha me esquecido deste detalhe. Mas mesmo assim la no site esta dando como não resolvido este problema. O que será que estou esquecendo ou interpretando errado?

Comment: Qual exercício está fazendo, de qual site? Precisaria ver para poder ajudar mais, principalmente se é um site com correção automática, ele vai te dar errado por um simples caractere no retorno.

Comment: O que o Anderson Carlos Woss disse nos comentários acima também é válido e eu não tinha notado. O exercício pede para você ler dois valores, não definir eles. O sistema vai inserir os valores em a e b, e seu algoritimo tem que somar os valores que o sistema que testa o código der. Ou seja, tente igualar 'a' e 'b' desta maneira:

    var a = prompt();
    var b = prompt();

Obs.: nunca fiz o uri em javascript, talvez a forma que ele leia os valores seja diferente.

Comment: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1001 estou pegando deste site que me indicaram para iniciantes, mas não sei o porque do problema

Comment: Lucas,

Fiz o teste em javascript lá, seguinte: Para ler os valores, você vai precisar fazer um código um pouco complicado, então vou te explicar o basico:

Você precisa igualar 'a' e 'b' a isto:  parseInt(lines.shift());

Explicando: o javascript não tem um comando exato para ler informações no console, como o C possui por exemplo o scanf(). Reparou que no começo do código em javascript tem duas linhas de código? Aquilo é para ele poder ler. lines é o objeto que vai receber os dados. Shift vai passar os valores, visto de modo bruto. e parseInt transforma em número a string.